# How to load multi-band geotiffs into Qgis for time series work

Tags: qgis

I'm new to Qgis, having used ENVI while I was at JPL. I have many time series of InSAR data showing surface deformation as a function of date. I stored them as multi-band geotiffs where each band is a date. How do I load all those bands (over 100 in some cases) into Qgis? I've downloaded the plugins called 'Raster time series manager' and 'EO time series viewer', but I can't get past the file reading step.
Thanks,
Tom Farr

addition: I found I can read the geotiff into Qgis with the Raster tool. A 5-band (date) geotiff will display ok in RasterTimeSeriesManager, but a 119 band geotiff will not. And RTSM doesn't seem to have the tools I need:  ability to get the time history of a pixel, subtract one date from another, etc. And EO Time Series Viewer won't load the data at all- I get a truncated error message that seems to not like missing dates or something.

Update: Ok, I figured it out- EO Time Series Viewer wants an aux.xml file with the dates spelled out for each band. Then you can load the stack. Took a few tries...

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This does not seem to be a coding question, and thus not appropriate for this site. You should have more response on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com)